# Using same spatial resolution for NDVI and LST data in machine learning model

Tags: ndvi, modis, resolution, machine-learning, land-surface-temperature

I am currently developing a drought forecasting machine learning model and this is my first time handling satellite data. Two of my data sources are the MOD13A1 dataset from Google Earth Engine for getting NDVI values and the MOD11A1 dataset for getting LST values. The region of interest is Southern California. The default resolution for MOD13A1 according to Google Earth Engine is 500m while for MOD11A1 it is 1000m.

If I need to use the same spatial resolution for both these products in order to maximize the performance of my model, what resolution would that be?